# Column add for 3 dimensional matrix

Tags: r

I have 15 members of datasets which all dimensions are `c(186,166,122)` where the first is `lat`, the second is `lon`, and the thrid is `time`.I want add extra column keeping lat and lon constant so that my new data format looks like where m1 to m15 has length of 122

```
 new=c(186,166,m1,m2,...m15)
```

I need an help who solve my problem.

Thanks
Bedassa

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of your data

Comment: @tokicha Do you have 15 3d matrices or is it a single 4d matrix?

Comment: I have 15 3d matrices and each has (186,166,122). The first and the second dimensions are the same for all matrices. The thrid is different for each. I want to create one matrix with common first and second dimenstion and from thrid to fifteen columns are the thrid dimensions from each matrix

Comment: @tokicha Array cannot hold variable dimensions.

Comment: What we can help with is create a matrix with 2+15*122 columns and 186*166 rows. Is that what you want?

Comment: @flodel let I have the following matrix: a1<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a2<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a3<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)) so I want to create I matrix  with five dimension  a<-c(2,2,a1[,,1:3],a2[,,1:3],a3[,,1:3])

Comment: @RichardScriven let I have the following matrix: a1<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a2<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a3<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)) so I want to create I matrix with five dimension a<-c(2,2,a1[,,1:3],a2[,,1:3],a3[,,1:3])

Comment: @akrun let I have the following matrix: a1<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a2<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)), a3<-array(runif(12),dim=c(2,2,3)) so I want to create I matrix with five dimension a<-c(2,2,a1[,,1:3],a2[,,1:3],a3[,,1:3])